# MSACCESS SQL Distinct Query

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access 2010 and am stuck. have a table with two columns FileID and Name for which there can be multiple names for a FileID. I need to obtain the distinct Name, and a FileID for each Name. I do not care which FileID is returned as long as one is returned.

Table:
FileID, Name
1, John
1, John
2, John
3, Simon
4, David

I would expect the result of 
3, Simon
 
4, David
and either 1, John or 2, John.

Would really really appreciate any advice on how this can be done in a query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an aggregation function:

```
select name, min(fileid) as fileid
from [table] t
group by name;
```

Access also supports `first()` and `last()`.  So, `first()` will get the first value encountered (as opposed to the minimum value):

```
select name, first(fileid) as fileid
from [table] t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you:

```
SELECT FileID, Name FROM [table] WHERE [conditions] GROUP BY Name;
```

This will return only 1 FileID, and return a record for every unique Name

Comment: You cannot group by just Name. If you select FileID then Group By expects FileID also. :(

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot that Access requires some sort of aggregate function on non-grouped columns. Gordon's answer provides a better solution.

Comment: Yes, his one works. THANK YOU for answering anyway!! Appreciated.